# Laravel - Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance. - Shopping Cart

Tags: php, html, laravel, cart

I get this error when i want to add a product in my cart.

`Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Cart.blade.php

```
  @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)

  <div class="cart-details">

    <div class="cart-img">
       <a href=""> <img src="{{ asset('storage/img/products/' . $item->image)}}" alt="item"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="top-box">
        <div class="title">
        <h2><a href="{{ route('shop.show', $item->model->slug)}}">{{$item->model->name}}</a></h2>
        </div>

  @endforeach
```

CartController

```
 public function index()
    {
        $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
        $products = DB::table('products')->get();

        return view('cart.index', ['products'=>$products,'cart' => null,'categories' => $categories, 'mode' => 'public']);
    }
```

Product.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $products->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $products->name}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $products->price}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="image" value="{{ $products->image}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#ff5400; border-color:#ff5400"><i
                class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> Acheter</button>
          </form>
```

{{ dd(Cart::content()) }}

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "4f2d2d0709b007102f7fe33cea201887" => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem {#311 ▼
      +rowId: "4f2d2d0709b007102f7fe33cea201887"
      +id: "20"
      +qty: 1
      +name: "Ori and the Will of the Wisps"
      +price: 55.0
      +options: Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions {#312 ▶}
      -associatedModel: "App\Product"
      -taxRate: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't if it because of the foreach or not ....

If someone can help me, thanks for your help !

Comment: make `{{ dd(Cart::content()); }}` on the first line inside foreach loop and post that in your question

Comment: Hi, show what you have in `Cart::content()`. `dd(Cart::content());` and open one of `item`;

Comment: I just edit my post with the dd(Cart::content()); . The image is not showing inside

Comment: You have multiple products in your query, do you want to show a single or multiple?

Comment: It's my cart so I want to show all the products that i add in my cart, that's why i'm using the foreach. In this case i just added one product that is "Ori and the Will of the Wisps"

Comment: Do you want to show multiple products in Products.blade.php that seems like what you are doing since you have a $products var?